# Скролинг страницы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Хочу сделать скролинг страницы, первый frame «уезжает» вверх, а второй встает на `top 0`, а вот третий не получается.

Как это исправить?

```js
var $document = $(document),
  $element1 = $('.frame-1'),
  $element2 = $('.frame-2'),
  $element3 = $('.frame-3');

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 1) {
    $element1.css("top", "-962px");
    $element2.css("top", "0px");
    $element3.css("top", "962px");
  } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 962) {
    $element1.css("top", "-1924px");
    $element2.css("top", "-962px");
    $element3.css("top", "0px");
  } else {
    $element1.css("top", "0px");
    $element2.css("top", "962px");
    $element3.css("top", "1924px");
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
}
.frame-1 {
  top: 0px;
  background: #c5d8c5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 962px;
  transition: all 3s ease;
}
.frame-2 {
  width: 100%;
  top: 962px;
  background: #99ff99;
  height: 962px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 3s ease;
}
.frame-3 {
  width: 100%;
  top: 1924px;
  background: #ff0000;
  height: 962px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="frame-1">
    <!-- Content here -->
  </div>
  <div class="frame-2">
    <!-- Content here -->
  </div>
  <div class="frame-3">
    <!-- Content here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Создайте jsFiddle с демонстрацией вашей проблемы.

Comment: http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/rmwkgcz5
на jsfiddle че то не могу создать

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что проверку позиционирования Вы делаете для `window`, а смещаете стилями блоки `$elemen1, $element2, $element3`, а это не одно и тоже, если бы Вы сделали смещение через `$(window).scrollTop(962)`. Т.е., что я хочу сказать, после смены позиции блоков, скажем, при первом скролле, значение `$(window).scrollTop()` на самом деле не будет равно `962px` и это можно увидеть через отладчик. Поэтому либо делайте проверку не для `$(window).scrollTop()`, а для, например, `$element1.css('top')`, либо меняйте позицию не для блоков, а для `window`, причем блоки условий необходимо поменять местами, т.к. проверка `if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 962)` не выполнится, ведь у Вас выше есть проверка `if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 1)` (согласитесь, все что `>962` будет `>1`), например:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 1924) {
        $(this).scrollTop(0);
    }
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 962) {
        $(this).scrollTop(1924);    
    }
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $(this).scrollTop(962);
    }
} /* правда, все скроллится если скроллить вниз */
```

Comment: если вам не трудно немогли бы вы скинуть ваш пример на jsfiddle

Comment: Я извиняюсь, не правильный код привел. Вот ссылка на рабочий вариант (повторюсь, только скролл вниз работает и нет анимации): http://jsfiddle.net/rkq5z62j/

Answer (score 0):

Ну так да.. Изначально неверный подход выбрали. Возьмите какое-нибудь готовое решение, например, fullpage.js. думаю, это то, что вам нужно

Comment: что то я там не разобрался совсем, большой скрипт, а разве не как не исправить мой код?

Comment: Что там сложного?. Пожключаете его на страницу после jquery. Вашим фремам добавляет класс .section, а к wrapper в скрипта своём подключаете $('.wrapper').fullpage();